# SSRS Report item shifting in the browser when compared to the design view

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, textbox, footer

I have a textbox containing Globals!PageNumber.ToString() in the right hand corner of my footer.  In Visual Studio's design and preview mode the textbox lines up perfectly with the Tablix above, in the body of the report.

The problem is, when the report is run in the browser, the Textbox shifts to the left and is no longer in line with the end of the Tablix above.  I have been struggling with this for several days and have carefully compared them with other reports and have found no differences.

Any advice or direction for this issue would greatly appreciated.  Even a link to another post would be great.  I have not had a whole lot of luck with Googling the problem

Comment: What browser are you using?, official Chrome compatibility comes from SQL Server 2014, also if you are using IE, check you are allowing "blocked content"

Comment: Thanks,I am using Google and have SQL Server 2014.  I tried IE and received the same results, even when I allowed the blocked content.

Comment: Delete the textbox, add a new one, put a hardcoded page number and check if it is showing correctly.

Comment: Same outcome.  I also deleted the other items in the footer and deployed it with just the hard coded page number but there was no change from before

Comment: I also created a rectangle and then placed a new textbox containing the page number within.  The rectangle still didnt prevent the textbox from shifting